# I preordered a game on my Xbox while on the home screen of my friend's account. Which of us owns the game?

Tags: xbox-one

When I downloaded the game I forgot to switch off my friend's account, does that mean that he owns the game now and I don't? I bought it on my Xbox so I should keep it right?

Comment: Did you input your own credit card info or was it already saved? You may have spent your friend's money and they now own the game.

Comment: You might consider contacting [Customer Support](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/contact-us).  They are more likely to have a way to help you if there is an issue.

Comment: In addition to Chippies comment, also don't forget to remove your credit card from your friends account.

Comment: An important lesson to be learned here (and this goes for all online accounts, not just Xbox): If you choose to log in on a device *you don't own,* make sure you remember to explicitly log out when you're done!

Answer (score 62):

Purchases are tied to an account, not a device. If you want to verify that you bought something on your Microsoft account, check your [order history](https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders/).

Answer (score 33):

As Alex Myers points out, you can verify which account the game was purchased on by checking the [order history](https://account.microsoft.com/billing/orders/). After checking which account the game was purchased on, there are one of two things that can be done:

1. If the game was purchased on your account, you do not need to do anything.
2. If the game was purchased on your friends account, you can submit a [digital product refund](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/billing/xbox-subscriptions/digital-goods-subscriptions-refund).

If the latter, you can follow the instructions on Microsoft's support site on how to fill out and submit the refund request. Without submitting a request, I did a test run to see how the process would go. During the Q&A, one of the options you can do is Accidental Purchase -> Used Wrong Account.

Since this is your friends account, you may need them with you in order to prove they are the owner of the account. After everything is good and the request is submitted, it may take up to 72 hours to hear from Microsoft's Support team.

Answer (score 16):

If you bought it using your *friend's account* then the game will be owned by him.

No matter what types of payment you use, the important thing is which account is the game goes to.

Answer (score 16):

Congratulations, you just bought your friend a video game. If you're worried about wasting your money, ask your friend to either pay you for it, or to return the game for a refund.

Comment: Honestly have no idea - is "returning for a refund" something that is even possible with a downloaded game?

Comment: @JPhi1618 There is a link to the digital product refund page in Wondercricket's answer.  I was also unaware of this until now.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Yeah, it is, ever since the Australian government fined Valve millions of dollars for violating Australian consumer law regarding the lack of refunds on Steam at the time.